# Retrieve rows within current month, week, and day using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table events with column `event_date varchar(10)` which takes in dates in the form `7-5-2014`.

I have an object which can give me:

```
// displays current month (5)
$m = $time->getMonth();
echo $m;

//displays current day (1)
$d = $time->getDay();
echo $d;

// displays current year (2014)
$y = $time->getYear();
echo $y;
```

I am trying to figure out a way to get events within the current day, month, and year.

The php query below is wrong but it gives you and idea as to what im trying to do:

```
$eventsWithinDay = query("SELECT * FROM events WHERE LEFT(event_date, 2)='%s'", $d);
```

How can I do this correctly?
Better yet, what is the most efficient way to do this?

I can make any necessary changes to the database or php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could use the MySQL function "unix_timestamp" and compare it that way. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp

Answer (score 0):

You an do it in various ways. For instance:

```
SELECT smth FROM somewhere WHERE datefield LIKE '2014-05-%'
```

OR

```
SELECT smth FROM somewhere WHERE datefield >= $start_interval and date <= $end_interval
```

In the latter case you'd have your date stored in a BIGINT column and use php's time() to set its value. Then using PHP's time functions (like strtotime('-1 day')) get timestamps for dates you wish to query against. So a simple example would be:

```
$q = "SELECT ... WHERE datefield >= " . strtotime('-2 days') // this would search for dates from at least 2 days ago
```

You could also use MYSQL's built-in date-time functions, but i have no experience with those so i'm not going to advice on something i don't know myself :)